# My URL has been excluded from google search console

Tags: wordpress

I have my website running on wordpress. Some of the pages have been excluded from the google search console but some of them got valid. The format of every page was the same. I don't know how this filtration has done. Can someone help me with this? I have added the screenshot and these are the reason gave by google [click to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKzOF.png)

Answer (score 0):

go to admin menu setting-> reading . uncheck "Search Engine Visiblity" option. refer below screens

[image]

Comment: I have already done this like a month ago. But still the error is showing